# How to properly reprocess using sqoop export to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I`m using sqoop to export data from hdbs into SQL Server. I'm trying to protect the system from partial processing... for example, the sqoop process runs then fails... I need to run it again, but I don't want to insert the same rows again.

I thought I'd use staging tables. But staging tables are not supported in SQL Server.

Then I thought I'd use updates with update mode: `allowinsert`.

Also not supported by SQL Server. I'm not sure what use an `Update` statement is, if I can`t allow for inserts.

Am I missing something...

Comment: What do you mean, *staging tables* are not support by SQL Server? You can easily just create a second table `YourTable_Staging` with the same structure and copy your data into that table first (to do some extra processing and possibly pruning before inserting into the real table)......

Comment: @marc_s, what I mean is that the sqoop option --staging-table isn't supported for sqlserver.